# Connect my andriod phone to pc without using usb cable

Tags: windows, android, file-transfer

I have pc with LAN connected and I dont have any wifi router. I want to connect my phone to PC without any usb plugin and how to transfer the files wireless. My phone uses different network to connect internet. Is there any possibility to connect my phone and LAN using two different networks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to start a wifi hotspot on the mobile device and then connect to that wifi network from your computer.

Then find an application such as an FTP server which will allow you to share files over FTP which can then be accessed on your machine most likely within your web browser by doing something like ftp://address-of-phone

If FTP does not work there will probably be a windows sharing applications availible in the mobile store market place.

Otherwise bluetooth?

Comment: Example of the apps? e.g. search for "site:https://play.google.com/store/apps/ server" on Google. Look for Samba if you want to try Windows sharing.

Comment: This would work, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserver

You could try a webserver also, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Many file explorer apps support remote file management over LAN shares & webservers. There are also 3rd party / OEM apps directly designed to allow you to manage & use your phone over network. They can support remote files, phone calls, messaging, notification monitoring etc. depending on which you choose. To name a few :

1. [Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)
2. [Xperia Link (Sony)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.xperialink)
3. [Share Link (Asus)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.sharerim)
4. [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender)

P.S : I'm not affiliated with any of above except being a user.